# How to match a pattern with exact occurence?

Tags: pattern-matching

Maybe the way I expressed is not very accurate, but a very simple example will help to understand the question:

For

```
Subscript[a,i]+Subscript[a,j]**Subscript[a,k]
```

I would like to replace a pattern that `a_i` shows exactly one time with some other symbol.

An intuitive way fails to work using `Except`:

```
Subscript[a, i] + Subscript[a, j] ** Subscript[a, k] /. 
 Except[Subscript[a, x_] ** Subscript[a, y_], Subscript[a, z_]] -> zz
```

The output is `zz + zz ** zz`. However, I would like it to be `zz+Subscript[a, j] ** Subscript[a, k]`.

The reason I need this is that I want to drop the linear term but keep the quadratic term of `a_i` by replacing only the linear term of `a_i` to zero.

Comment: Look at `Subscript[a, i] + Subscript[a, j] ** Subscript[a, k] // FullForm`. That should explain why the pattern does not match.

Comment: @Rohit Namjoshi, Thanks! I understand why it fails now. But is there a workaround that can realize my idea?

Comment: `Subscript[a, i] + Subscript[a, j] ** Subscript[a, k] /. 
 Plus[a___, b_Subscript, c___] :> a + zz + c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do

```
Subscript[a, i] + Subscript[a, j] ** Subscript[a, k] /.
  {a_NonCommutativeMultiply :> a, Subscript[a, z_] -> zz}
```

> ```
>   zz + Subscript[a, j] ** Subscript[a, k]
> ```

because [`ReplaceAll >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

- "ReplaceAll *looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr. The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts.*